# UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone did not work

Tags: uitableview

In the `UITableView`, I want to change text color and selection style of cell by scanflag (boolean).

(code is in - `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  method)

(and when scanFlag is changed, table is reloaded)

```
if (scanFlag) {

            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //Work
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue; //Work
}else {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; //Work
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;  //Did not Work
}
```

When I change scanFlag yes to no, `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`; does not work, even though `[UIColor lightGrayColor];` is working.

('>' shape of cell is not disappeared.)

Should I send bug report to apple ? (Is this bug?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not bug. UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone is applied for the selection style only and not for navigation. When the style is set to none and when users taps any row the selection is not highlighted. And if you not want the > then set "cell accessory" to None

Hope this helps.

**Cell without applying UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone**

[image]

**Cell after applying UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone**

[image]